# OOM Error when Loading a List of Bitmaps Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, scaling

I'm trying to create a solitaire card game in android, so I'm attempting to load images for a full deck of cards (53 images total, 52 for the fronts and one for the back of the cards). The images load in just fine, but then when I try to scale them to fit the screen for any device, I get an out of memory error usually around the 13th card. Here is my method to scale the cards:

```
public ArrayList<Card> mapBitmapToCard(ArrayList<Card> listOfCards, ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfImages, int screenHeight){
        ArrayList<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 51 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            Card card = listOfCards.get(i);
            card.setScaleFactor(screenHeight);
            Bitmap cardFront = listOfImages.get(i);
            listOfImages.remove(i);
            card.image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cardFront, (int) (cardFront.getWidth() * card.scaleFactor), (int) (cardFront.getHeight() * card.scaleFactor), true);
            cardFront.recycle();
            Bitmap back = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.card_back));
            card.back = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(back, (int) (back.getWidth() * card.scaleFactor), (int) (back.getHeight() * card.scaleFactor), true);
            back.recycle();
            result.add(card);
            System.out.println("" + (52 - i) + " cards completed");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Are there any ways to fix this ore accomplish this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate thought is not to load all of them then scale all of them.  Scale them immediately after load, then recycle the original image immediately. That way rather than 53 unscaled and n scaled images at any one time, you have 1 unscaled and n scaled.

It also looks like you're creating 52 different copies of the scaled back image.  Don't do that.  Scale it once and reuse the same reference-  making 52 copies is a waste of memory and likely your problem.  The back is the same anyway for all 52 anyway isn't it?

Comment: You probably also don't need to pre-load all 52 card fronts. See if you can load them quickly enough on-demand.